# what happen if I use 7zip to compress EFS-encrypted files to create a new zip

Tags: windows-7, encryption, zip, efs

is the EFS-encrypted files decrypted automatically and save to the new zip file?

So I can give the zip file to another user/external parties, to open it without any EFS keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EFS is transparent to programs, i.e. data is decrypted on fly and thus zip tool will pack that data without any encryption.

Assuming you create that file without at unencrypted location of if you copy file to disk that doesn't support it (e.g. external FAT32 flash), no EFS keys will be required.

Comment: thanks Josip, yes, all I understood is it will decrypted on the fly, when move from NTFS to non-NTFS / network location. But what if the zip-tools create the zip in the NTFS? Sorry my english is not good, I hope you know what I concern... thanks a lot

Comment: If it is created on NTFS, it depend on whether parent folder is encrypted. If parent folder is encrypted, then the newly created file is going to be encrypted by default. But that applies only for zip file - internal content of zip file is unencrypted. So, if you want resulting zip file not to be encrypted, either create it in non-EFS location (even if it is on NTFS) or remove the encryption attribute from it post-fact. Either way you get to use unencrypted file.

Comment: Yes, I has also consider to un-EFS the files first, and then zipping them....But finally I understood that it is not need. Because, once the zip-tools create the zip, the zip-tools is opening the files to get the data-stream, it is already decrypting them on the fly, so the files packed in zip container is already decrypted "plaintext"...I have try it and it works, by zipping the EFSed files, move the zip file to network drive. Then I remove my private key from user profile, then try to open original EFSed file, it fail, then try to unzip the zip and open the extracted file, it success!